# Whether sparql federated query supports query from multi-graph?

Tags: sparql

I want to use [sparql federated query](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/#service) to select from multi-graph, but find errors:

```
Parse error: Encountered " "from" "FROM "" at line 5, column 5.
```

sparql:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  SERVICE <sparql endpoint> {
    SELECT *
    FROM <graph 1>
    FROM <graph 2>
    FROM <graph 3>
    WHERE { ... }
  }
}
```

I want to know whether sparql federated query supports query from multi-graph.

Best regards

Comment: it is not possible to define the dataset in the `SERVICE` clause

Comment: but you can try to put the named graphs into the SPARQL endpoint URL via `using-named-graph-uri` param, see https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-protocol-20130321/#query-operation

Comment: or you simply use the named graphs in the query pattern itself, e.g. with the `VALUES ?g {...}` clause and then `GRAPH ?g { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @UninformedUser

I solved this question with multiple [default-graph-uri](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-protocol-20130321/#query-operation) params . This can make `graph_1`, `graph_2`, and `graph_3` all to be loaded into the default graph .

SPARQL request:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  SERVICE <http://xxx/sparql?default-graph-uri=graph_1&default-graph-uri=graph_2&default-graph-uri=graph_3> {
    SELECT *
    WHERE { ... }
  }
}
```